# Should the [spl] tag be used?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

Dennis Haarbrink and I just had a little conversation about the [spl tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spl) (SPL is the `Standard PHP Library`) on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811551/recursiveiteratoriterator-last-child).

In my opinion the tag is, more or less, synonymous with `[php]`, pretty similar as if I'd tag a C# question with `[System-Data]`. It further limits the scope of the question but doesn't add anything of value to it.

Should this tag be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SPL can also refer to:

- [The Shakespeare Programming Language](http://shakespearelang.sourceforge.net/report/shakespeare/shakespeare.html)
- [Stored Procedure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stored_procedure) Language

Although neither of these are popular topics on Stack Overflow, it doesn't mean that they wouldn't be in the future.  This makes it less viable to add SPL as a synonym of PHP.  It's also worth noting that the percentage of questions tagged `[php]` that are also tagged `[spl]` is tiny.

With only 43 questions, I think a manual cleanup is enough.  Remaining vigilant could help keep the tag off future PHP questions too.